# How to split a List into "n" number of sublists in Java? User will input the value of "n"

Tags: list, split

Say I have the below-mentioned list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Now, if user wants 4 sub-lists (n=4), then the sub-lists will be

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
[6,7,8,9,10,11]
[12,13,14,15,16,17]
[18,19,20]
```

Similarly, if user wants 6 sub-lists (n=6), then the sub-lists will be

```
[0,1,2,3]
[4,5,6,7]
[8,9,10,11]
[12,13,14,15]
[16,17,18,19]
[20]
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: Just divide the length of the list by n. round it to next integer (k)  and then create first n-1 groups with size k. Then create the last sub-list with remaining of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

n=6
k = int(len(list1)/float(n))+1
i=0
for x in range(n-1):
        i=(x+1)*k
        print list1[i-k:i]
print list1[i:]
```

Try this python code. It answers your problem perfectly.